# How do I take the minimum value from another row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

Apologies for the rather ambiguous title, I couldn't put it in a better way.

I have the following records in my output.

| route_id | date | employee_id | stop_type | vehicle_stop_number | enter_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-16 | ABC | Pickup | 1 | 2021-06-16 15:06:39.000000 |
| 1 | 2021-06-16 | ABC | Pickup | 2 | 2021-06-16 15:27:35.000000 |
| 1 | 2021-06-16 | ABC | Dropoff | 3 | 2021-06-16 16:36:42.000000 |
| 1 | 2021-06-16 | ABC | Station | 0 | null |

What I want is to basically get the min(enter_time) when stop_type = 'Dropoff' and paste it in the 'Station' row

| route_id | date | employee_id | stop_type | vehicle_stop_number | enter_time_actuals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-16 | ABC | Pickup | 1 | 2021-06-16 15:06:39.000000 |
| 1 | 2021-06-16 | ABC | Pickup | 2 | 2021-06-16 15:27:35.000000 |
| 1 | 2021-06-16 | ABC | Dropoff | 3 | 2021-06-16 16:36:42.000000 |
| 1 | 2021-06-16 | ABC | Station | 0 | 2021-06-16 16:36:42.000000 |

Some edge cases are that when a Dropoff enter_time is null then Station enter_time should also be null, there can also be multiple 'Dropoff' in that case I would want the earliest time.

This is what I have been trying:

```
SELECT *
    , CASE
          WHEN stop_type = 'Dropoff'
              THEN MIN(enter_time)
                   OVER (PARTITION BY date, route_id, employee_id, stop_type, vehicle_stop_number)
          ELSE null END as min_dropoff_enter_time
    , CASE
          WHEN (stop_type = 'Station' and enter_time is null)
              THEN min_dropoff_enter_time
          ELSE enter_time END as enter_time_updated
FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM stops
    )
```

Comment: So, you want a simple select statement, or you want to update an another column ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select route_id, employee_id, stop_type, vehicle_stop_number,
        case when enter_time is null and stop_type ='Station' then
        (select min(enter_time) from stops where s.route_id = route_id and stop_type = 'Dropoff') 
        else enter_time end
        as enter_time_actuals
from stops s
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select s.*,
       (case when stop_type = 'Station'
             then min(case when stop_type = 'Dropoff' then enter_time end) over (partition by route_id) 
             else enter_time
        end) as imputed_enter_time
from stops s;
```